# Incorporating Japanese rice malt into a beer recipe?

Tags: beer

I bought two jars of rice malt syrup today and I am looking for a beer recipe I can use it in.  I am thinking of mixing it with hops and molasses.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

Rice malt extract is nice - it usually has all the properties of barley malt extract, except different, much lighter maltiness.

Because this lack of heavier malt flavors, it's great to showcase hop flavor and taste. Take any extract recipe for hoppy ale, for example AIPA, and substitute some of barley malt extract for your rice malt extract. And that's pretty much it.

Do not add molasses. It has strong, un-beery taste and is only good as an adjunct for some styles. As a main taste and aroma? I strongly discourage it now. Try adding some to belgian dark strong ale, or to stouts, see the effect, and only use it as a main taste / aroma ingredient when you know how it works and no longer need to ask.